# XSLT SUM() is not working as expected even with the correct xpath (xml version="1.0" encoding='utf-8')

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt, sum

I've been trying to get the sum of the `PaymentAmount/Value` under `<CtrlSum>` tag. I have 2 transactions being returned by the `<NbOfTxs>` tag. However, I was only able to get the first value from the first transaction and not the sum of all `Value` under `OutboundPayment`.

The selection used to get the values is:

```
<xsl:for-each select="OutboundPayment[count(. | key(&#39;contacts-by-LogicalGroupReference&#39;, LogicalGrouping/LogicalGroupReference)[1]) = 1]">
  <xsl:sort select="LogicalGrouping/LogicalGroupReference"/>
  <PmtInf>
    <PmtInfId>
      <xsl:value-of select="$instrid"/>
    </PmtInfId>
    <PmtMtd>TRF</PmtMtd>
    <BtchBookg>TRUE</BtchBookg>
    <NbOfTxs>
      <xsl:value-of select="../InstructionTotals/PaymentCount"/>
    </NbOfTxs>
    <CtrlSum>
      <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(PaymentAmount/Value), &#39;##0.00&#39;)"/>
    </CtrlSum>
```

.
.
.
*the rest of the xsl script...*

Expected Output:

```
<NbOfTxs>2</NbOfTxs> --NbOfTxs
<CtrlSum>300.00</CtrlSum> --CtrlSum
```

Actual Output(ctrlsum is incorrect):

```
<NbOfTxs>2</NbOfTxs> --NbOfTxs
<CtrlSum>100.00</CtrlSum> --CtrlSum
```

Comment: Please post a **reproducible** example, including the XML input - see: [mcve].

Comment: On the face of it, it looks like you are performing Muenchian grouping and want to sum the values of the current group. But your code selects only the value of the first item in the group - see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76351321/3016153. But without a [mcve] that's just a wild guess.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(PaymentAmount/Value), &#39;##0.00&#39;)"/>
```

try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(key('contacts-by-LogicalGroupReference', LogicalGrouping/LogicalGroupReference)/PaymentAmount/Value), '0.00')"/>
```

As already stated in the comments, this is no more than an educated guess.

Comment: This actually worked, super thanks!!! May I ask the logic behind this syntax?

Comment: The logic is explained in the comment to your question: you are using the correct expression to select the first item in each group in your `xsl:for-each` instruction. But when you need to select the items in the current group, the correct expression to use is: `key('theGroupingKey', 'theCommonValue)`. You used only `theCommonValue` which selects the value of the context item - i.e. the first item in the current group.